# Identify 400-request with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, twitter

I'm having the following problem:

I am grabbing tweets from twitter, using their API. Whenever I've hit the limit of requests, it is returning me a 400 (Bad request) - reply.

Now, how can I find out whether a 400-reply was returned? The callback 'Error' isn't triggered.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/' + Followed[Index] + '.json?count=' + Tweetlimit + '&include_rts=true',
            dataType: 'jsonp', 
            success: function (json) {
                $.each(json, function (index, tweet) {
                    var date = Date.parse(tweet.created_at);
                    Tweets.created_at = date.toString('hh.mm.ss - dd/MM/yy');
                    Tweets.created_as_date = date;
                    Tweets.push(tweet);
                })
                CompletedUsers = CompletedUsers + 1;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            },

        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`success` is called when request succeeds. `error` is called when request fails. So, in your case, request succeeded and `success` is called. Now, if you want to respond to specific codes, you should follow this example in addition to your code:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert("page not found");
    }
  }
});
```